# How to get the right select/option selected from mysql-db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a edit page where I can edit the status of a message.

```
<select name='cm_status'>
option value='Open'>Open</option>
<option value='Closed'>Closed</option>
</select>
```

Then I change the status to closed, but when i go into the page again, the open  is selected even when the status is set to closed, and I wonder how to get the closed one selected.

Thanks in advance,

Kristian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to query the database when the page loads and create the form after evaluating the results.

You will set the attribute `selected=selected` on the option value depending on the value received from the database.

Here is a simple version of what you will need:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT cm_status FROM some_table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)
echo "<select name='cm_status'>";
if($row == "Open")
echo "<option value='Open' selected>Open</option><option value='Closed'>Closed</option>";
else
echo "<option value='Open'>Open</option><option value='Closed' selected>Closed</option>";
echo "</select>"
```

This form will need a form handling PHP script that will update your MySQL database table using `$sql="UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = 1 WHERE mytable_id = 1";`

Comment: Hello, I have done something similar, to that.  I used If statements, to check if status = closed, then echo the selected.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast, and helping me out! :) Both of you :

Comment: @ashin999 Thanks for expanding on my answer!